# Sharepoint 2010 - Creating Web Part Zone without using Sharepoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have created a page that has a top left and top right web part.  The left web part will hold the navigation and the right will hold the body.  When the two web parts are displayed they are vertical and I need them side by side (horizontal).  Due to requirements the quick launch navigation will not work for us.

I figured that I need to create a web part zone and change the orientation to horizontal - Everywhere I look it says to use SharePoint Designer to create the web part zone and my company has turned off Sharepoint Designer usage.

Is there another way to create the web part zone or to get my two part parts side by side?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've been creating Web Part Zones for the past several months amd sadly to say that I can only create Web Part Zones in SharePoint Designer using **Edit File in Advanced Mode**.